# How to prevent invalid data insert SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle, sql-insert

In my project, I need to check conditions dynamically. To achieve this create table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE myconditions 
( 
     conditionid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
     minvalue    INT, 
     maxvalue    INT, 
     result      INT 
)
```

and there data containing as follows,

```
insert into MyConditions (MinValue, MaxValue, Result)
values (10, 20, 1), (20, 30, 2), (null, 10, 3), (30, null, 3)
```

I use this table data to check the range of the age,

```
declare @age int = 25 --this represents user age

select *
from MyConditions
where @age > isnull(MinValue, @age - 1)
  and @age <= isnull(MaxValue, @age)
```

but now the problem is, suppose if someone inserts an invalid range, such as `values (5, 25, 4)` i mean this is invalid, because in the database already have `(10, 20, 1)` this values. when the `@age = 15` both condition will be through. so I need to prevent `(5, 25, 4)` this values addition. if someone needs to add this `(5, 25, 4)` range, This range values `(10, 20, 1)` should be deleted.

I insert those data into the database using an ASP.NET MVC application. How can I do this? In my project Is using Oracle. (in this question I used MS SQL sample code, but I need oracle)

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter plz help me

Comment: @APC I'm really sorry sir, In this question I used sample ms sql code, but i  plan to use oracle . so please help  me, sorry for the something I did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of data integrity validation is very difficult to implement in a robust and performative fashion.

For starters, much depends upon the definition of overlapping range. For instance it could be argued that all your sample data ranges are invalid:  `maxvalue = 10` overlaps with `minvalue = 10`, assuming bounds are testing with `>=` and `<=` which is default. Likewise, `null` bounds create complexity: if you have an existing range `(30, null)` is `(40,50)` valid?

So once you have sorted out your business logic there's the matter of implementing them. In Oracle  we can do something with a compound trigger. For each row we store the ID of the inserted / updated row in an array. Then at the end of the statement we loop through the array and query the table in a cross join to compare the date ranges.

```
create or replace trigger myconditions_trg 
  for insert or update of minvalue, maxvalue 
    on myconditions 
  compound trigger 

  type condition_array is table of int 
    index by binary_integer; 
  conditions condition_array; 

  procedure validate_range (p_id in int) is 
    overlapping_range exception; 
    dummy char(1); 
  begin 
    begin 
      select null into dummy 
      from myconditions t1 
          , myconditions t2 
      where t1.conditionid = p_id 
      and t2.conditionid != p_id 
      and t1.minvalue != t2.minvalue 
      and ( 
           t1.minvalue between t2.minvalue and t2.maxvalue 
           or 
           t1.maxvalue between t2.minvalue and t2.maxvalue 
          ) 
      and rownum = 1; 
      raise overlapping_range; 
    exception 
      when no_data_found then 
        -- what we're hoping for, no overlaps found
        null; 
    end; 
  exception 
    when overlapping_range then 
      raise_application_error(-20000, 
        'overlapping range for id #' || p_id); 
  end validate_range; 

  procedure validate_ranges is 
    l_id int; 
  begin 
    l_id := conditions.first; 
    loop 
      exit when l_id is null; 
      validate_range (l_id); 
      l_id := conditions.next(l_id); 
    end loop; 
    conditions.delete; 
  exception 
    when others then 
      conditions.delete; 
      raise; 
  end validate_ranges; 

  BEFORE EACH ROW is 
  begin 
    -- store id to validate 
    conditions(:new.conditionid) := 1; 
  end before each row; 

  AFTER STATEMENT is 
  begin 
    validate_ranges; 
  end after statement; 

end myconditions_trg;
```

This trigger doesn't attempt to handle multi-user scenarios. To be honest there's not much we can do to prevent two different sessions creating overlapping ranges. The only thing which is guaranteed is to lock the whole table, but that may not be desirable.

If you're interested I have a published a demo on Oracle LiveSQL (free login required, sorry!). [Find it here.](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/g2qfcrcyb0uc6oyconp0zja7q)

Comment: Thank you, sir. really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either a trigger or a user-defined function for this.

A simple `check` constraint can only check the values in a single.  Frankly, I think a trigger would be the more common approach.

The exact syntax for either depends on the database -- and you have specified two of them -- so a more detailed answer isn't feasible.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code to do that sir. please. how to write a trigger or function to do that. how to do it using Oracle SQL

Comment: please help me sir. please :( I'm really stacked on this. how to write trigger or function for this